# Problem updating a table after insert using trigger in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

I'll start by explaining how the db should work:
In this example I have a table that stores work orders, this table has 5 total fields: ID, Number, Worker, temperature, humidity.
And another table that stores sensor data with 4 fields:  ID, Device ID, Temp, Hum.

We built an APP that allows workers to submit work order data, **My problem comes here** The app generates the ID, Number and Worker field, and we want to add the sensor data (Temperature and humidity) to that table every time an insert is made. I tried doing this with a trigger but i get "Error Code: 1442. Can't update table 'ordenes' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger."

I tried multiple ways of doing it but I either get no change on the table or that error message.

Im looking for a way to do this:

```
trigger after insert
> insert into "new created line"(temperature, humidity) values
 (select temp,humidity from sensors order by id desc limit 1)
```

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

Create Scheme and table:

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';

CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `Cegasa` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
USE `Cegasa` ;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Cegasa`.`ORDENES` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Cegasa`.`ORDENES` (
  `idORDENES` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `NumOrden` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Empleado` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Temperatura` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Humedad` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idORDENES`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Cegasa`.`sensores` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Cegasa`.`sensores` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `EUI` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Temp` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Hum` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

USE `Cegasa`;

DELIMITER $$

USE `Cegasa`$$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `Cegasa`.`ORDENES_AFTER_INSERT` $$
USE `Cegasa`$$
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `Cegasa`.`ORDENES_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `ORDENES` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
insert into `cegasa`.`Ordenes` (
`temp`,
`hum`
) SELECT temp,hum FROM sensores ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1;
END$$

DELIMITER ;

SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Insert for example sensor data:

```
INSERT INTO `cegasa`.`sensores`
(`id`,
`EUI`,
`Temp`,
`Hum`)
VALUES
(default,
"th312322aa",
"10",
"33"),(
default,
"daedaf12392",
"30",
"70"
);
```

Similar insert to the one the app makes

```
INSERT INTO `cegasa`.`ordenes`
(`idORDENES`,
`NumOrden`,
`Empleado`)
VALUES
(default,
1,
"123a");
```

[Desired outcome after this insert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1IkG.png)

Comment: @Akina added the stuff, trigger doesn't make any sense but it's the last one I tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sensores` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `EUI` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Temp` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Hum` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
INSERT INTO `sensores` (`id`,`EUI`,`Temp`,`Hum`) VALUES
  (default, "th312322aa",  "10", "33"),
  (default, "daedaf12392", "30", "70");
SELECT * FROM sensores;
```

| id | EUI | Temp | Hum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | th312322aa | 10 | 33 |
| 2 | daedaf12392 | 30 | 70 |

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ordenes` (
  `idORDENES` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `NumOrden` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Empleado` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Temperatura` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Humedad` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idORDENES`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

```
CREATE TRIGGER get_last_Temp_Hum
BEFORE INSERT ON ordenes
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  DECLARE new_temp VARCHAR(45);            -- declare intermediate variables
  DECLARE new_hum VARCHAR(45);
  SELECT Temp, Hum INTO new_temp, new_hum  -- select vast values into it
  FROM sensores
  ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
  SET NEW.Temperatura = new_temp,          -- set columns values in newly inserted row
      NEW.Humedad = new_hum;               -- to the values stored in the variables
END
```

```
INSERT INTO `ordenes` (`idORDENES`,`NumOrden`,`Empleado`) VALUES
  (default, 1, "123a");
SELECT * FROM ordenes;
```

| idORDENES | NumOrden | Empleado | Temperatura | Humedad |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 123a | 30 | 70 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/BLuZ8Xbv)

Trigger fires on INSERT statement but before the values are inserted into the table (i.e. the insertion is an intention yet). The query in the trigger retrieves needed values into the variables, then SET statement copies these values into the columns in the row which will be inserted. And after the trigger finishes the row contains needed values in the columns, and these values are saved into the table.